# Cloning a table line in Javascript - How to remove slected option?

Tags: javascript, clone, selectedvalue

I am cloning a table line with Javascript,
Step 1: cloning OK

But cloning copies data.
i want to set all inputs to 0 or null.
it works for all input types but i am unable to have it work with a select-option

I tested with number, text, checkboxes.... all ok except select

Here my code:

```
<?php

<table ID="trig_strava_register_to_single_contest">
      <thead>
          <th>
            <h3>-</h3>
          </th>
          <th>
            <h3>Username</h3>
          </th>
          
        </thead>  
   <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
             <td>
                <select name="trig_strava_register_to_single_contest[]" >
                    <option value="" >--Please choose an option--</option>
                    <option value= "1" > 1 </option>
                    <option value= "2" selected> 2 </option>
                    <option value= "1" > 3 </option>
                </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>

            <p>
            <INPUT type="button" class= "button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('trig_strava_register_to_single_contest')" />
              <br>
            <INPUT type="button" class= "button" value="Delete Selected Rows*" onclick="deleteRow('trig_strava_register_to_single_contest')" />
```

here my Jscript

```
function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var rowHeadCount = table.tHead.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    
  
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
  
      var newcell   = row.insertCell(i);
      newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0+rowHeadCount].cells[i].innerHTML;

      switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
        case "input":    
            newcell.childNodes[0].value = 0;
            break;
        case "date":    
            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "1999-12-31";
            newcell.childNodes[0].setAttribute('value',"1999-12-31");
            break;
        case "time":    
            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "00:00:00";
            newcell.childNodes[0].setAttribute('value',"00:00:00");
            break;
        case "select-one":
            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            break;
           
        default:
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = 0;
                newcell.childNodes[0].setAttribute('value',0);
           
                break;
       
      }
    }
  }
```

What am i doing wrong
or does select behave differently from input?

Comment: Is this really your working code because `table.tHead` is undefined as there is no `<thead />` within your table?

Comment: Call `removeAttribute("selected")` on the appropriate `select` element.

Comment: @Ian: Thead added

Comment: @Scott, my problem is how to hook the removeAttribute("selected") . I can't find a way to get the SELECT in the CHILDNODE

Comment: SOLVED: the issue was the space between <TD> and <SELECT> that generates a ChildNode
the JS was indexed to [0] and did not get the node

will rewrite teh JS code to loop into Childnodes

Comment: @Bud: please don't, if you want elements then just use [`newcell.children[0]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children), or [`newcell.querySelector('*:first-child')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: @DavidThomas - thanks, i need to loop anyway in the AddRow function, inside the newcell elements:
this function will be used in cases where there are multiple elements or nodes in the same cell.
i need to set to null all elements in this case not just the first (0).
i will loop in children rather than in Childnodes

Comment: Do not call JavaScript "JScript". That is already a thing that hopefully dies in a fire since IE is now dead. Call it by its full name, or simply "JS".

Answer (score 0):

The error was in a space between  and . the space is consideredd a ChildNode

to fix this I changed the JS to loop into the childnodes and changing the index of childnode from [0] to a relative index

```
function addRow(tableID) {

var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var rowHeadCount = table.tHead.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

  var newcell   = row.insertCell(i);
  newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0+rowHeadCount].cells[i].innerHTML;
  
//added the childnodes lenght (count) to loop through  the childnodes (previously set at [0]) 
  var the_node_count = (newcell.childNodes.length); 
    for (let x = 0; x < the_node_count; x++) {
        switch(newcell.childNodes[x].type) {
            // case "number":    
            //     newcell.childNodes[x].value = 0;
            //     break;
            case "input":    
                newcell.childNodes[x].value = 0;
                // newcell.childNodes[x].value = null;
                break;
            case "date":    
                newcell.childNodes[x].value = "1999-12-31";
                newcell.childNodes[x].setAttribute('value',"1999-12-31");
                break;
            case "time":    
                newcell.childNodes[x].value = "00:00:00";
                newcell.childNodes[x].setAttribute('value',"00:00:00");
                break;
            case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[x].selectedIndex = 0;
                break;
            
            default:
                    newcell.childNodes[x].value = 0;
                    // newcell.childNodes[x].setAttribute('value',0);
                    newcell.childNodes[x].selectedIndex = 0;
                    break;
        
        }   
    }   
}
```

}